# Dynamical script loading in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to dynamically load some javascript on a page. I have the idea to make a content script that will check some condition for choosing which scripts to load.

My problem is that I don't know how to load a script. I have already tried JQuery `getScript()` function but it use unsafe-eval call. I have also found `chrome.tab.executeScript()` but it can't be use in Content scripts.

I have to do it form Content Script because it have to check some contion on the page BEFORE loading scripts. I don't want to load all my scripts each time a page is loaded.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Send a message to your background page and in the message listener download the external script with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to a variable and insert it with [chrome.tab.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)`({code: downloadedCode});` or [as a webpage script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/3959875)
2. Include these scripts in your extension, list them in ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and inject [as a webpage script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/3959875) setting the added `<script>` element's `src` attribute to `chrome.runtime.getURL("that_script_name")`.

Comment: I know I can do this. But it's not what I'm asking for. I want to load my scripts form a content script. Because I will not load always the same script. I choose which script I want to load by checking some condition on the content of the page.

Comment: Send a message to your background page from the content script. Or use the second method from the answer. What's the problem?

Comment: Humm yes I haven't think about send a message with the list of script to load... It's an idea. But all the content of the script will be global... I wanted to do some thing like an "include" in other languages...

Comment: What do you mean `content of the script will be global`? You can insert the new script into the tab that sent the message, I can add an example if needed.

Comment: I mean that defined function in that script will be added to the global namespace. And I only need it in the definition of one of my Angular Controllers. But I don't think it's possible to do better...